# Does RESTEasy support tunneling?

Tags: java, jax-rs, resteasy

As mentioned in Restlet docs it has feature called ["tunneling"](http://wiki.restlet.org/docs_2.0/13-restlet/27-restlet/331-restlet/207-restlet.html). Does this feature exist in RESTEasy too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Servlet below supports "tunneling" by delegating "method" parameter from request.

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher;


public class TunnelingDispatcher extends HttpServletDispatcher {

@Override
protected void service(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
        HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) throws ServletException,
        IOException {
    String method = httpServletRequest.getParameter("method");
    if (method == null) {
        method = httpServletRequest.getMethod();
    } else {
        method = method.toUpperCase();
    }
    service(method, httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);
}

}
```